# Passing guid as query in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a unit test that returns object models and fails:

```
[HttpGet, HttpHead]
[Route("{id}", Name = RouteNames.GetById)]
[ResponseType(typeof(Api.BusinessEvent))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid id)
{
    return await GetOrStatusCodeAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(true);
}

[TestMethod, TestCategory(Unit)]
public void BusinessEventController_Get_Returns_InternalError()
{
    // arrange
    var scope = new DefaultScope();
    var expectedQuery = new Api.BusinessEvent();
    scope.BusinessEventProviderMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync())
        .Throws(new Exception());

    // act
    var actual = scope.InstanceUnderTest.Get(expectedQuery)
        .AssertInternalError(ApiErrors.Generic);

    // assert
    actual.Should().NotBeNull();
    scope.LoggingProviderMock
        .VerifyLogApiError(scope.ExpectedLogCategories, ApiErrors.Generic);
}
```

I am getting this error on the expectedQuery variable:

> Cannot convert from 'Model.BusinessEvent' to 'System.Guid'

How would I create the query so that it's input would be a guid?

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: The method under test is expecting a `Guid` and you are trying to pass a `Api.BusinessEvent`

Comment: `Get()` accepts `Guid` and **returns** `Task<IHttpActionResult>` which (I guess) is `OkNegotiatedContentResult<BusinessEvent>`. Now please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the actual variable to return  System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult but it returning System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult.

Comment: @DavidTunnell, has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid id)
```

and the current example provided, it looks like you need to change `expectedQuery` from

```
var expectedQuery = new Api.BusinessEvent();
```

to a variable type of `Guid`.

For example:

```
var expectedQuery = Guid.NewGuid();
```

All the other code in your example looks like custom code specific to your environment. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is only left up to assumptions and guesses as to what the other code does. This limits quality of answers you can get.

Hopefully my observation is accurate and that it solves your issue. Otherwise you will have to refine your original post.